# Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3 provided

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to execute ggplot with these codes but it continuously gives the same error.

```
> brookeana_pca_plot <- ggplot(data = brook, aes(x = pc1, y = pc2, colour = Morph)) + geom_point(size = 2) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green")) + theme_bw() + xlab("Principal component 1") + ylab("Principal component 2")
>  brookeana_pca_plot <- brookeana_pca_plot + geom_polygon(data = ch, aes(fill = Morph, colour = NA), alpha = 0.2) + ggtitle("O. Brookeana") + theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "italic"))
> brookeana_pca_plot
```

Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3 provided.

Comment: The error is really self-explaining. You don't specify enough colors in `scale_color_manual`
.

Comment: `unique(brook$Morph)` should show you that there are 4 different values, which doesn't match the number of colours that you've provided.